# ngCordova Email Composer +how to check if user cancelled?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have a Ionic v1 app and today I added the ngCordova Email Composer (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/emailComposer), which is a kind of wrapper for https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.

It is working till the point where I want to know, if the email was sent correctly, or if the user cancelled. I found some exmaples over Google, but they catch always a cancel, even if the mail was sent.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Christian.

Answer (score 0):

The issues list of the plugin (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/issues) shows, that I am not the only one, having problems.